# I have created table Using Material UI. I need to include checkbox to show or hide the tables. How i need to include. Below is my source code. resolv

Tags: checkbox, hide, footer, show, head

I have created table Using  Material UI. I need to include checkbox to show or hide the tables columns.

"songs": [
{
"movie": "Aradhana",
"title": "AajaTujako",
"songLength": "4:45",
"singer": "Rafi",
"genre": "Romantic",
"id": 2
},
{
"movie": "MungaruMale",
"title": "Anisuthide",
"songLength": "5:45",
"singer": "SonuNigham",
"genre": "Romantic",
"id": 3
},
{
"movie": "Ashique",
"title": "EkaSanamChahiye",
"songLength": "3:25",
"singer": "KumarSanu",
"genre": "Romantic",
"id": 4
},
{
"movie": "Rambo2",
"title": "Na Manege Barakilla",
"songLength": "3:25",
"singer": "Vijay  Prakash",
"genre": "Comedy",
"id": 5
},
{
"movie": "Kalasipalya",
"title": "Suntargali Suntargali",
"songLength": "3:25",
"singer": "Rajesh Kishnan",
"genre": "Mass",
"id": 6
},
{
"movie": "Pogaru",
"title": "Donagalu Rowdigalu",
"songLength": "3:25",
"singer": "Chandan Shetty",
"genre": "Mass",
"id": 7
}
]
}

Comment: <Table className={classes.table}>
          <TableHead>
              <TableRow className={classes.thead}>
                  <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Movie</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>SongLength</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Singer</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Genre</TableCell>
                  <TableCell></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>

Comment: .map(song=>(

            <TableRow className={classes.row}>
               
            <TableCell>{song.id}</TableCell>
            <TableCell >{song.movie}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{song.title}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{song.songLength}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{song.singer}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{song.genre}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>